# Write MXML Code in Actionscript3

Tags: image, actionscript, mxml

I have the following MXML Code but I need to run it from Actionscript. How can I write this in AS? Thanks a lot!!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo"
        applicationComplete="applicationCompleteHandler()">

  <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

      private var bannerIntegration : BannerAd;

      public function applicationCompleteHandler():void
      {
        Security.allowDomain("*");

        bannerIntegration = new BannerAd(banner);
      }
    ]]>

  </fx:Script>
      <s:Image id="banner" width="300" height="250"/>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is just from memory so it might need some tweaks:

Basically you would create a normal

`class SpecialApplication extends Application {`

In your IDE or mxmlc call you choose SpecialApplication as the class to build.
Inside the class you have the properties as you have them now:

```
private var bannerIntegration : BannerAd;
private var banner:Image;
```

everything else is simple to answer for your example but I'm sure this is not the complete application, so you should read something about the Flex Lifecycle (be careful that you look at the right one: the one for Flex 3.* is a bit different from the one in Flex 4.*)
So ideally

`override protected function createChildren():void {`

to create and add UI elements:

```
if (image == null) {
    image = new Image();
    image.width = 300;
    image.hight = 250;
    addChild(image);
    bannerIntegration = new BannerAd(banner);
}
```

I'm not sure if `Security.allowDomain("*");` requires some special timing maybe you can also do it inside `createChildren()`.
Otherwise you can have the same method that you have in your script block above (with an additional `event:FlexEvent` argument), to do this call. Just do

`addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, applicationCompleteHandler)`

inside the constructor.

The `if` inside `createChildren()` is there to make sure to only create ui elements once. As `createChildren()` will be called each time this component is added. (Not so important inside Application, but a good habit for creating components using ActionScript classes.